# Adding CalTasks from an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSArray of Strings and what I want to do is create a new CalTask (for the calendar store) for every String, I want the Name of the task to be the string that is being added, the Priority and Due Date to be set in the code.

For example I have an array with the Strings `To-Do 1`, `TD 2`, `TD 3`.
So I want to create 3 CalTasks, the first one with the Name `To-Do 1` and the second with the name `TD 2` etc. See what I'm talking about. But I want all the Priorities and Due Dates to be the Same.

Comment: I answered your question about example code 2 days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455497/using-calender-store/1455743#1455743. You'll get better replies if you actually tried to write some of this yourself.

Comment: Ok. Ok.  I just wondered if I had to do something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is loop over the NSArray and create and add a new CalTask with a predefined priority and due date:

```
// Set up the array
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TD1", @"TD2", @"TD3", nil];

// Get the calendar
CalCalendarStore *store = [CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore];
CalCalendar *calendar = [[store calendars] objectAtIndex:0];
// Note: you can change which calendar you're adding to by changing the index or by
// using CalCalendarStore's -calendarWithUID: method

// Define priority and due date
NSDate *dueDate = [NSDate date];              // By default due now - change as needed
CalPriority priority = CalPriorityMedium;     // By default medium - change as needed

// Loop, adding tasks
for(NSString *title in array) {
    // Create task
    CalTask *task = [CalTask task];
    task.dueDate = dueDate;
    task.priority = priority;
    task.title = title;
    task.calendar = calendar;

    // Save task
    NSError *error = nil;                   
    if(![store saveTask:task error:&error]) {
        // Diagnostic error handling
        NSAlert *anAlert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
        [anAlert runModal];
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I get no errors in XCode, but after triggering the Action there are still no new tasks/to-dos in iCal.

Comment: Make sure you do error-handling at the marked point - if the calendar store doesn't get updated, this sample code will produce no messages. Also possibly add more `NSLog()` statements throughout the code to see what's happening where. Once you've done that, please provide more specific info about what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Ok. I put a NSLog message saying Error where you put `// Do error-handling`. And i got 3 Log messages saying error, one for each string in the array.

Comment: @Joshua, I've changed the `Save task` section. See if that gives you an idea about how to use `NSError`s.

Comment: OK. This would be my bad: the `calendar` object I created wasn't valid to add tasks to. Instead, what you should do is pull a calendar from the store. I've updated the answer to correct.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Calendar Store Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/CalendarStoreProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: It tells you how to create a Task, but not specifically with an Array.

Comment: Have you ever programmed anything in Objective-C?

Comment: @Joshua: how hard is it to loop through an array?  How hard is it to look at the example code on how to create a Task?   http://bit.ly/nYcjp

Comment: Yes, I have. I looked at the example code thank you very much. But I didn't know you could loop through an array.